# Introductions to Disease- and Price-Modeling

Tags: books, mathematical-modeling

I'm looking for resources (anything from short articles to books) about building mathematical models or computer simulations of 'things that happen' in populations.

Specifically, I'm curious about 1) epidemic modeling and 2) pricing in virtual economies. (Not sure if the latter is just mathematical economics? My interest is in the economics of online, World of Warcraft-type communities in particular.)

Comment: -1. Please actually ask a question.

Answer (score 6):

I can't comment on the economics side of things, but for epidemiology a good reference is:

Brauer, Driessche, and Wu, "Mathematical Epidemiology"

(http://books.google.com/books?id=gcP5l1a22rQC&dq)

It gives a series of articles in the field that cover everything from basic SIR models up, though it does not attempt to unify the presentation--it's just a series of articles.

J.D. Murray's "Mathematical Biology," which is in two volumes, is also widely used and liked, and has several sections on population and disease modeling.